# Get URLs from image Key in Python

Tags: python

I need to get 'image' : values, but nothing which I have tried, worked.

I've tried to convert to dict, but no success. Tried json, but no success too.

```
[
    {
        "image": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/.../61070103916_8222623480192096121_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com",
        "thumbnail": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/.../61070103916_8222623480192096121_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com",
        "ts": "8382423"
    },
    {
        "image": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/..../7366801460_3370303770835888477_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com",
        "thumbnail": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/.../7366801460_3370303770835888477_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com",
        "ts": "8283861"
    }
]
```

It`s expected an output like:

````
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/.../61070103916_8222623480192096121_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/..../7366801460_3370303770835888477_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com```
````

Comment: show what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this whole thing into list and each list item will be converted to dictionary, and you can then loop through it and get "image" from each dictionary.

```
img_list = [
        {
            "image": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/.../61070103916_8222623480192096121_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com",
            "thumbnail": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/.../61070103916_8222623480192096121_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com",
            "ts": "8382423"
        },
        {
            "image": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/..../7366801460_3370303770835888477_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com",
            "thumbnail": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/.../7366801460_3370303770835888477_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com",
            "ts": "8283861"
        }
    ]

for i in img_list:
    print(i["image"])
```

Output:

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/.../61070103916_8222623480192096121_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/..../7366801460_3370303770835888477_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com
```

Comment: avoid using list as a variable name since it is a reserved word

Comment: A for loop work`s very well, but is it possible to use a list(map()) to speed up?